# What is the best way to identify those rows with data have changed in the Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

- I'm using Ag-grid with Angular1;
- And my own custom cell renderer.
- "version": "5.4.0"

I want to have an array that will have only the rows in that any cells was been changed, to be used in a service that will do the update of those data.

I've tryed the cellValueChanged event, but doesn't work for custom editor;

I've been searching in Row Models, but I didn't find on the three models the way of get the changed data; e.g. could be with an event listener but:

"addEventListener(eventType: string, listener: Function): Add an event listener. Currently only rowSelected event supported."

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I see that there is an event called cellValueChanged that is an event of the [gridOptions.](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/index.php) Have you tried using that?

Comment: Yes, I've tryed the cellValueChanged event, but doesn't work for custom editor. Unfortunately that is my case.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue? If so could you please post it here so others can be benefited. Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortly not. What I did was get the whole table and test the difference to save editted rows.